# Upgrade Ubuntu on certified Dell laptops

Tags: dell

Is it advisable to install Ubuntu 22.04.01 on a Dell Laptop which is certified for ubuntu 20.04?
Cause I upgraded to 22.04 on a Dell 13 9310 there seem to be problems with Wayland and chrome where sharing screen is buggy and flickering etc. Actually it doesnt even work under wayland, just xorg and its buggy. and it doesnt even have a nvidia card.

Now I am thinking if 20.04 would work any better, cause thats what the machine is certified for.

Appreciate any hints. thanks.

Comment: btw, I downloaded and installed the official ubuntu 22.04  and not dell-flavored.
Is it possible that the dell-flavoured (or pre-installed) Ubuntu 20.04 has a custom kernel?
I am reading something about OEM kernel...

Comment: Please edit your question to show your specific 20.04 Dell OEM kernel source (there are several possible) from your apt sources. Your problems might be due to the kernel, but they might have other causes. Dell has typically kept up with Ubuntu kernel releases for the past decade, and as recently as GUADEC 2022 clearly stated that they intended to keep doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, I put my contribution directly in the answer because I still don't have enough reputation to leave a comment directly, which would be the right thing to do.

In principle, there should be no problem if you use a more current version of Ubuntu, since with each version updates capable of solving known problems or improvements within the distribution are installed.
You should install new updates within the official repositories to see if that solves your problem with the following command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

However, I have to tell you that the procedure to update to a new version of Ubuntu is one-way, that is, once you update to version 22.04 you cannot go back to version 20.04. The only way to achieve this would be through a complete reinstall.

Comment: Thank you for the input.
I just read that DELL has their own ubuntu version with a custom kernel. What I am asking now if using that version would solve my problem which I have with the non-dell Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You can read more information about installing Ubuntu on Dell computers here:

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131655/c%C3%B3mo-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-computer

Comment: "*Their own ubuntu version with a custom kernel*" is not completely accurate. Some models with certain newer components do require custom kernel modules (OEM kernel) for those components until those modules are accepted into the mainline kernel. There is no intent to keep Dell users on OEM kernels permanently; the intent has always been to migrate customers to mainline kernels when all hardware is supported. Older models have indeed migrated from OEM to mainline as intended.

Comment: I understand. Laptop in question was certified on OEM Kernel 5.6.0, so by now the specific modules should have been migrated into the mainline kernel?
how about fixed bugs, i.e. in i915, like here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1978252 
do they stay first in OEM for a while before being merged?

Comment: AskUbuntu is poorly suited to followup questions. We have a Question/Answer format, not conversation threads. If you want it answered, it should be part of your original question (which you can edit). Note that it is considered rude to edit a question so much that existing answers no longer apply.In those cases, open a new question.

Comment: @vinc_de : you can always install newer drivers e.g. with DKMS , just  check that they are freely available  and not "only issued once by [D/H]ELL"